# Unable to link OpenCV code with gcc

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, linker, makefile

I have this very simple C++ file

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   using namespace cv;
   Mat m = imread("image.jpg");
   imwrite("image2.jpg",m);
   return 0;
}
```

And my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
   add_executable(foobar test.cpp)
   include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   target_link_libraries(foobar ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)
```

OpenCV includes are in `/opt/local/include`, the libs in `/opt/local/lib` (MacPorts installation, but I tried manually compiling with another version in `/usr/local` with the same result). I get the linking error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
```

Now I could switch to `clang`, but I want to try `OpenMP`, so `gcc` it shall be. Besides, it bugs me and I have no idea what's wrong. Does it have to do with how OpenCV was compiled (with `gcc` or `clang`)?